# Virt Manager is not opening on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, kvm, qemu, python3, virt-manager

I have installed virt manager from terminal using command `apt-get install virt-manager` in ubuntu 18.04. 
It is installed successfully but when i click on VirtManager App icon it is not opening.
When i tried to run the command `virt-manager` from the terminal it will tell like this 
`python 3.4 or later is required, your's is sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=15, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

I have already installed python and python3.

`python --version` gives -->Python 2.7.15+

`python3 --version` gives -->Python 3.4.4

Any help is really appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: At SO a similar question [was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964998/virt-manager-not-working-on-ubuntu). [Changing the python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970027/how-do-i-update-pythonpath-from-usr-local-bin-python-to-usr-bin-python/29970431#29970431) should solve the problem:

Comment: I tried in two ways: 
1. edited bash_profile like `alias python='/usr/bin/python'` 
2. edited bash_profile like `alias python='python3'` 
 but still, i have the same issue.
`python 3.4 or later is required, your's is sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=15, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: This is interesting. I'm using Mint 19.2, same code base as Ubuntu 18.04. My `virt-manager` points to **/usr/share/virt-manager**, which uses python2 (1st line is `#! /usr/bin/python2`). Curious where you got python 3.4.4; mine's @ 3.6.9.